# jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: index.html for simple hello world program in flask

Tags: python, flask

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
return "Hello World!" 

if __name__=="__main__":
app.run()
```

when I running the above code, I got the error "jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: index.html" evenif for simple hello world program. if anyone have solution please guide me.

Comment: the code you are running works perfectly. Maybe there is a naming error: what is the name of your python source file?

Comment: The code you have in your question is not the code causing this error.

Comment: c:\Users\HP\Desktop\LEARN FLASK\Scripts>

Comment: file name: simple_flask_hello.py

Comment: this code doesn't use templates so it can't give this error. The only idea: you run totally differen code - maybe you edit wrong file. Better see what paths show error

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: sir this is the common error, prompted when I execute every program of flask

Answer (score 0):

Create a folder called templates which contains all HTML files and include this.

```
app = Flask(__name__, template_folder="templates", static_folder='static')
```

Comment: sir actually its a simple hello world program I think it don't need any templates folder

Comment: Then why do you have index.html?

Answer (score 0):

This error is caused when you attempt to return, via render_template an html file that cannot be found.  They should be stored in a templates folder like this:

```
yourproject/
    app.py
    templates/
        index.html
```

However your code makes no reference to either render_template or index.html. Why don't you update your question so that it applies to your error?

If you want to call your templates folder something other than templates then per another answer you could look to use something like this:

```
app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='MyPreferredTemplateFolderName')
```